# Azure Container Instance - Unsupported windows image .net framework 4.8

Tags: .net, azure, docker, containers

I am trying to create a container instance in Azure portal using a custom image that I had created based on **mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8**

When I am trying to do so, I get the error saying that "Unsupported windows image version. Supported versions are 'Windows Server 2016 - Before 2B, Windows Server 2019 - Before 2B, Windows Server 2016 - After 2B, Windows Server 2019 - After 2B, Windows Server, Version 1903 - After 2B, Windows Server, Version 2004'".

I have an application that needs .Net Framework 4.8 to be running on the container. That was the reason that I had to select the above base image.

Could anyone help me in how to resolve this issue or any other alternate base image that has .net framework 4.8.

Comment: can you check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/571182/windows-version-base-image-it-is-not-compatible-wi.html) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because version of window OS is using for build that image is not same as The version of windows of the nodepool on AKS/Container instance. Would suggest you use same Window OS to build the Images as it thrwoing in error.

Simillar kind of issue has raised in [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49705) as well.

[image]